# Twitter-API confusion with since_id and max_id

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am writing a JavaScript application using Twitter API that searches for all recent tweets related to a search term for every 30 seconds period.

If given a time, say 1441910342000, I want to get the count of all the tweets since that time until now. Then after 30 seconds, I will look for tweets from 1441910372000 until now.

I don't seem to understand how this since_id works. Giving that time to since_id returns me tweets before that time and not the ones that have been tweeted since then. I read through the documentation so many times but still I'm not able to understand why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The primary role of since_id and max_id are to help you page through data. Keep track of max_id so that you don't accidentally re-read tweets you've already processed on previous queries. Use since_id to know how many tweets to read on the current query without exceeding max_id. Together, they box the tweets that you haven't processed yet to avoid reading redundant tweets. The following article, from the Twitter documentation, shows this graphically and explains why this is an efficient way to page through tweets:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines